# Android phone not showing on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've already looked at other questions with the same issue, but they all say to update the device drivers, well the driver for my phone is fully updated and it still won't show up in Eclipse, also my USB debugging IS activated. I also tried to make a virtual device but whenever I run the project the virtual device just stays on the shining android screen, but I would rather have the project run on my phone than in a virtual environment.

Used PDANet and this guide http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/06/how-to-set-up-adb-usb-drivers-for-android-devices/

Resolved the issue

Comment: When u type adb on cmd does it work if so type adb devices to see if ur device is listed

Comment: What @Immanuel.I.George was probably trying to say: What happens when you type `adb devices` on a command prompt? If your device is properly connected, that command should display an entry.

Comment: I just get 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: ye it will say List of devices attached the list it below

Comment: Okay it means ur adb is not yet setup. Follow the instructions here http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/06/how-to-set-up-adb-usb-drivers-for-android-devices/

Comment: Navigate to sdk/platform-tools first then execute adb. The command is there. Use adb devices to lost the connected devices.

Comment: List of devices attached
-BLANK-
I'm guessing that my drivers didn't install correctly

Comment: is your phone rooted? i've had problems myself, testing apps with rooted phones.

Comment: No, my phone is not rooted, I've only had it for about 2 weeks and I've done nothing shady to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered that problem before but as installing [Moborobo](http://www.moborobo.com/) in my PC solved it.

Answer (score 0):

try ---- first check ur phone is detect in DDMS if not then check ur mobile version then set mobile version to min target in android manifest ..